# Function that returns the first column values based on the other columns?

Tags: r, lapply

I'm starting with a data.frame similar to this in R:

```
data <- data.frame(Names=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), E1=c(NA, 1, 0, 4), E2=c(3, 0, 0, NA))

  Names E1 E2
1     A NA  3
2     B  1  0
3     C  0  0
4     D  4 NA
```

My goal is to create a list that shows the Names where the value of each column is nonzero, zero, or NA. In other words:

```
[[1]]
$Nonzero
"B", "D"
$Zero
"C"
$N/A
"A"

[[2]]]
$Nonzero
"A"
$Zero
"B", "C"
$N/A
"D"
```

So far I've written the following function:

```
my.function <- function(x) {
  nonzero <- which(x!=0 & !is.na(x))
  zero <- which(x==0 & !is.na(x))
  na <- which(is.na(x))
  rows <- list("Nonzero"=nonzero, "Zero"=zero, "N/A"=na)
  return(rows)
 }
```

Then I used lapply:

```
lapply(data[,-1], my.function)
```

The result is this:

```
[[1]]
$Nonzero
2, 4
$Zero
3
$N/A
1

[[2]]]
$Nonzero
1
$Zero
2, 3
$N/A
4
```

So I've got the row numbers, but now I can't figure out how to get to the Names from here. My real data set has ~50  columns so I definitely need some thing I can use with lapply, rather than doing it separately for each column. Advice is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I should add that I would like this function to be transferable for use on other datasets. Thus inserting the name of this individual dataset into the function will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very quick fix is:

```
library(magrittr)
my.function <- function(x) {
    nonzero <- which(x!=0 & !is.na(x)) %>% data$Names[.]
    zero <-    which(x==0 & !is.na(x)) %>% data$Names[.]
    na <-      which(is.na(x))         %>% data$Names[.]
    rows <- list("Nonzero"=nonzero, "Zero"=zero, "N/A"=na)
    return(rows)
}
```

Then call

`lapply(data, my.function)[-1]`

Because you don't want the list results for column "Names".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! The problem with this solution for me is that I would like this function to be transferrable to use on other data sets as well. And so inserting "data" directly into the function will not allow me to do this.

Comment: I did not insert data. Please make an example where your function does not work anymore.

Comment: What I mean is that this function includes the name "data" (my specific dataset used in this example). However if I wanted to apply this function to anything that was not named "data", it would not work.

Comment: Actually I have thought of a solution to this. I just need to insert a line in the function to say "data <- x" and that should allow me to use it on anything. Thanks for your help!